# FBX export with textures does not work

Tags: materials, export, .fbx, text-object

I have a very simple blender project, a cube with a simple shader and a texture:
[image]

I want to export my simple blender project in FBX format, including the texture, so I set the FBX export parameters like this:
[image]

But when I open the FBX file in Unity or with Windows 3D Viewer, there is no texture and the colour I decided on in the shader (red) is not red but white.

The texture and the blender project is in the same folder, i followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYf4QnzXynQ&ab_channel=GameDevTrauminEnglish)

This is actually just a test, because I have a more complex blender project to export and in both cases I have the same problem.